# Parsing a table with BeautifulSoup & Selenium & trouble

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I've made a programme to access internal company site to retrieve order QTY data on the hour every hour. Access is fine, but trying to retrieve the data is an issue as it's in confusing table format. Cannot access through back end.

```
driver.get("companyurl") #fetching the site & feeding to beautifulsoup
url = driver.page_source("companyurl")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
#this is where the issues start
```

TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable (line 2)

also having issues retrieving the table itself with the soup, but that's another day another dollar

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the page source the Selenium driver received straight into BeautifulSoup for parsing:

```
driver.get("companyurl")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Then try searching for your table:

```
all_tables = soup.find_all('table').get_text()
```

Or if you know it's placement:

```
a_table = soup.find_all('table')[1].get_text()
```

Comment: worked perf, final code is (worked it out after a couple of days)

    `driver.get("company url")` 
    `url = driver.page_source`
    `soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")`